# How to use dynamic pivot table in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My goal is to create a dynamic pivot table in Bigquery, to do so I was planning on:

- Declaring an array based on a select distinct
- Using this array in the pivot statement FOR .. IN UNNEST(ARRAY)

Here is the sample code :

```
DECLARE cat ARRAY <STRING> ;
SET cat = ( SELECT  ARRAY_AGG( distinct product_category_level_3) FROM categories );


SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        customer_id
        , product_category_level_3
        , last_variant_bought_id

    FROM table
)PIVOT(
    MAX(last_variant_bought_id)
    FOR product_category_level_3 IN UNNEST(cat)
)
```

However this raise a Syntax error: Unexpected ")" at the end of the query.
I cannot figure out why is it happening ?
Any thought on this error or the best approach to do this ?

Best

Answer (score 2):

Need to declare `STRING` variable, then `EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE`

```
DECLARE cat STRING ;
SET cat = ( SELECT  STRING_AGG( distinct product_category_level_3) FROM categories );

EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE """
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        customer_id
        , product_category_level_3
        , last_variant_bought_id

    FROM table
)PIVOT(
    MAX(last_variant_bought_id)
    FOR product_category_level_3 IN (?)
)
"""
USING cat
```

Comment: Please, provide some data samples

Comment: I get the following error using this method: Generating an implicit alias for this PIVOT value is not supported;