# How to get dates as column names in SQL BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-view, sql-date-functions

I would like to get dates (monthYear,weekYear,etc.) as columns, and having the value as count activities by users, but i'm not reaching it :(

Some example:

- My table

| userid | activityId | activityStatus | activityDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | z1 | finished | 2022-08-01T15:00:00 |
| A2 | z2 | finished | 2022-08-07T20:00:00 |
| A2 | z3 | finished | 2022-08-08T10:00:00 |
| A1 | z4 | finished | 2022-09-17T16:00:00 |
| A1 | z5 | finished | 2022-09-20T17:00:00 |
| A3 | z6 | finished | 2022-08-19T13:00:00 |

What I'im trying to do, something like this (but I know now that's not working):

```
SELECT
userid,
COUNT(activityId) as doneActivities,
CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR from activityDate),'-',EXTRACT(WEEK from activityDate))
```

And the result of this attemp is like:

| userid | doneActivities | weekYear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 31-2022 |
| A1 | 2 | 33-2022 |
| A2 | 1 | 31-2022 |
| A2 | 1 | 32-2022 |
| A3 | 1 | 33-2022 |

- Expected result would be something like this:

| userid | 31-2022 | 32-2022 | 33-2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| A2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| A3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I know how to do it on Power BI, but I want to automate this for futures queries.

If it's not clear, please let me know guys, and I'll try to explain again. There is some time that I don't practice english.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Since BigQuery doesn't support [`dynamic pivoting`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator) (using variables as column names) at this point (maybe due to security issues), [some way around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260216/how-to-use-dynamic-pivot-table-in-bigquery) is needed.

However, the basic idea of approaching the problem would be first using (static) [`PIVOT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#pivot_operator). And then changing the query to string and do [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate).

#### PIVOT

```
WITH
dataset AS (
    SELECT 'A1' as userid, 'z1' as activityId, 'finished' as activityStatus, DATETIME('2022-08-01T15:00:00') as activityDate,
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A2', 'z2', 'finished', '2022-08-07T20:00:00'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A2', 'z3', 'finished', '2022-08-08T10:00:00'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1', 'z4', 'finished', '2022-09-17T16:00:00'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1', 'z5', 'finished', '2022-09-20T17:00:00'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A3', 'z6', 'finished', '2022-08-19T13:00:00'
),
preprocess_dataset AS (
    WITH
    _dataset AS (
        SELECT *, CONCAT('_', EXTRACT(YEAR from activityDate), '_', EXTRACT(WEEK from activityDate)) as year_week,
        FROM dataset
    )
    SELECT userid, year_week, COUNT(DISTINCT activityId) as done_activities,
    FROM _dataset
    GROUP BY userid, year_week
)
SELECT *,
FROM preprocess_dataset
PIVOT (
    SUM(done_activities) FOR year_week IN (
        '_2022_31', '_2022_32', '_2022_33', '_2022_37', '_2022_38'
    )
)
ORDER BY userid
;
```

#### Results

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on to the great answer of @JihoChoi, if you would like to implement dynamic pivoting. See approach below:

```sql
create temp table my_table (userid string,doneActivities int64,weekYear string);

insert into my_table
select
  userid, 
  count(distinct activityId) as doneActivities, 
weekYear
from
  (
    select
      *,
      concat('_',extract(YEAR from activityDate),'_',extract(WEEK from activityDate)) as weekYear
    from `project-id.dataset_id.table_id`
  )
group by userid,weekYear;

execute immediate (
  select '''
    select * from my_table
    pivot(sum(doneActivities) for weekYear in ("''' ||  string_agg(weekYear,'", "')  || '''"))
  '''
from (select * from my_table order by weekYear)
)
```

Output:

[image]

[image]